# How to use ft_elementwise_product

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml, sparklyr

I am trying to use function `ft_elementwise_product` which is supposed to make elementwise product, but I can´t, here is a link explaining how the function should work:

http://rstudio.github.io/sparklyr/reference/ft_elementwise_product.html

Having this example:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

iris2 = copy_to(sc, iris, "iris2", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I wanted to multiply Sepal_Length with Sepal_Width, so I tried:

```
ft_elementwise_product(iris2, Sepal_Length, Sepal_Width, Sepal_Width) 
# object 'Sepal_Length' not found

ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", Sepal_Width, Sepal_Width) 
# object 'Sepal_Width' not found

ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", Sepal_Width) 
# Error in object %||% default : object 'Sepal_Width' not found

ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Sepal_Width")
# Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched method found for class org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct.setScalingVec

ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Sepal_Length")
# Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched method found for class org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct.setScalingVec

ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", "result", "Sepal_Length")
# Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched method found for class org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct.setScalingVec

iris2 = mutate(iris2, result = 0)
ft_elementwise_product(iris2, "Sepal_Length", "result", "Sepal_Length")
# Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched method found for class org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ElementwiseProduct.setScalingVec
```

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to multiply Sepal_Length with Sepal_Width

In that case you have not use for `ElementwiseProduct`. Just use standart multiplication:

```
iris2 %>% mutate(product = Sepal_Length * Sepal_Width)
```

> How to use ft_elementwise_product

`ElementWise` product is a ML `Transformer` used with `Pipelines`. It is used to multiply `Vector` columns by local scaling `Vectors`. With current master (`0.7.0-9105`) it can be used as shown below:

```
iris2 %>%  
  # Create Vector column which can be used as an input
  ft_vector_assembler(input.col=colnames(.)[-5], output.col="features") %>% 
  # Transform assembled vector with vector [-1, 1, -1, 1]
  ft_elementwise_product(
    input.col="features", output.col="scaled_features",
    scaling_vec=c(-1, 1, -1, 1))
```